# I can't build 64x project in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, 64-bit, badimageformatexception

I created a **extremely simple solution** in visual studio 2010, this solution has:

- A class library...and a class named "HelloWord"
- ASP.NET web site project...and one page inside it named "Home.aspx"
- Home.aspx calls "HelloWord" class

Problem: I have a Win7/64x machine and i want this project to compile as 64x (not Anycpu)...when i try to run i receive this message

> System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly...

Why?

Comment: are you sure both library and website are compiled to x64

Comment: Yes, i right clicked the solution >configuration properties>configuration and every project is 64x

Comment: i am wondering if you don't have to set sth for the host server process to be run as x64.

Comment: i don't know how to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to discover a way to make it work

1-) Run your your project as "Any CPU"

2-) Force the IIS to run the "aplication pool" as "32bit = false"